# Editing CSS (changing selectors) at runtime with JavaScript: prevent application inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mediawiki

I would like to be able to prevent a CSS file from applying to the inside of a DIV tag.

The CSS file is included in the `<head>` section of a HTML document. I cannot remove the file or change it. All I have control of is the inside of that DIV tag. The HTML document is generated with MediaWiki, so I'm not allowed to use iFrames. I cannot host my content anywhere else, but I can take external resources such as CSS and javascript, upload them, and include them in the inside of my DIV.

Currently, I have Jquery, and I can include all sorts of external libraries.

Using jQuery to find the `<link rel="stylesheet" href=...>` and then `.remove()`ing it does work, but that messes up the rest of the page, which I am prevented from doing by a LOT of red tape.

Is there a way to "javascriptically" do something to the stylesheet such that it applies only to anything that's not inside my DIV? Maybe using the `:not()` selector?

I have no idea, and I have never touched the `not` selector before. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged 'mediawiki'?

Comment: because the hosting HTML document is done by mediawiki. I'm trying to do some fancy javascript styling inside a MediaWiki page. They let me use html tags such as script and <style>, but MediaWiki processes everything to and adds code before and after. I'm trying to deal with a stylesheet from the code added before mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make prevent CSS from applying to a part of the document, even if you could change it (which is doable with Javascript as long as you don't care about users with no Javascript). You have two options basically:

- Override the CSS. Probably the least painful way is to take some [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) stylesheet and prefix every rule so that #1 it only applies to your div, #2 it has high enough specificity to override all MediaWiki rules. You can then apply your own styles on top of that.
- Make the div not part of the document. You could create an iframe in Javascript and move the contents of the DIV there. (Shadow DOM would be a nicer approach but there is not much browser support yet.)